# Как исправить ошибку 'float' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, pandas

Записываю данные из csv в бинарный файл.

Как только доходит до пустого столбца (8-ой столбец на примере ниже), где нет ничего, а только разделитель, то выдает ошибку:

```
'float' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Вот пример из csv, на котором происходит ошибка:

```
78;99;Ararat Yerevan;FF;Ararat;FF;Ararat;;128;128
```

В файле не всегда 8 столбец пустой, в основном там какие либо названия, как в третьем столбце, но иногда бывает пустым и тогда ошибку выдает.

Записываю так:

```
def writeStr(file, s):
    encodedStr = s.encode("UTF-8")
    writeInt(file, 4, len(encodedStr))
    file.write(encodedStr)

writeStr(datFile, club['Position-8'])
```

Пробовал заполнять в csv файле пустой столбец чем либо, будь то 0, тогда все проходит нормально. Но когда столбец пустой, тогда выдает такую ошибку. Как можно исправить?

Также пробовал так:

```
writeStr(datFile, str(club['Position-8']))
```

Ошибки нет, в бинарный файл записывает, но неверно. Нужно чтобы пустые столбцы записывались как 0, а получается почему то 7233902.

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы не попробовать обработать через исключение?

```
def writeStr(file, s):
    try:
        encodedStr = s.encode("UTF-8")
    except AttributeError:  # Если пустая строка то..
        encodedStr = "0".encode("UTF-8")
    writeInt(file, 4, len(encodedStr))
    file.write(encodedStr)
```